# Nginx location behave with and without location regex

Tags: nginx

To include my small project (not based on one of the known frameworks) into existing website, I've added the following config to Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.error.log;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    [...]

    location /www.my-project.com {
        alias /var/www/www.my-project.com/web;
        index index.php;
        if (-f $request_filename) { break; }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /www.my-project.com/index.php last;
        location ~ /[^/]+/index\.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgi.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
        }
    }
```

All works fine (except that I wish to prevent to list subdir name in location directive), so I can call `http://localhost/www.my-project.com`. But when calling `http://localhost/www.my-project.com.blabla` the location directive from above is called and my internal error page is served. So I tried to change location directive to

```
    location ~ ^/www\.my-project\.com(/|$) {
```

But that causes any existing file (CSS, JS...) to be rewritten to index.php, which then returns an 404 itself. Why does a change of location causes this horrible behaviour, I can see no logical difference between `location /www.my-project.com` and `location ~ ^/www\.my-project\.com(/|$)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest excluding the assets from the rewrite, you can do that by adding a new location, something like this

```
location /(css|js|images) {
    root /var/www/www.my-project.com/web;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

And for the location issue, you can match exact locations using `=`

```
location = /www.my-project.com {
```

Comment: This would be an approach. Therefor it's a bit work to list all files, that are served from root (/) statically (like robots.txt and others). But I'll accept your answer as it points me to use `location = /project-dir { return 301 /project-dir/; }` and `location /project-dir/ {` (perhaps you could improve your answer)